# how to javascript scrollto in an embedded iframe on a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, iframe, scrollto

I have what I think should be a simple thing to do but everything I've tried has been a bust.

I have an iframe in a mobile web page, looks nice, finger swipe scrolling in the major os's without any code. But I'd like the iframe to open the map.html to a specific coordinate, the map.html is just an image of a map, nothing else.

Code on the page embedding the iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe2" width="292" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="map.html"></iframe>
```

Code for map.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<div style="width:292px;height:350px;frameborder:1;marginheight:0;marginwidth:0;overflow:scroll;" >
<img src="images/map.png">
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Is there some javascript that I could put on either the page holding the iframe or in the map.html that would scroll map.html to something like 50px,50px?

Comment: You hate your users, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll give up on this idea... embedded the image in the page instead of iframing an HTML page, then set user-scalable=yes, (it's a mobile thing)... I was hoping for something more elegant, but this is eminently usable and simple to build.

Thanks anyways!

Maybe that was Shmiddty's point, one of those 'what is the sound of one hand clapping?' sort of questions/lessons!!!